# Sort on embeddedId in Spring data

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class who has an `@EmbeddedId`

```
@Entity
public class Samples {

    @EmbeddedId
    public SampleId id;

    @MapsId("samplingId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Samplings sampling;

}

@Embeddable
public class SampleId implements Serializable{

    private Integer samplingId;
    private String sampleLetter;

    public SampleId() {

    }

    public SampleId(Integer samplingId, String sampleLetter) {
        this.samplingId = samplingId;
        this.sampleLetter = sampleLetter;
    }
}
```

In database sample, `samplingId` is position 0 and `sampleLetter` is position 1;

In paging of Spring Data JPA, if I do a sort on id I get

```
Order by
        samples0_.sample_letter,
        samples0_.sampling_id asc
```

So Spring Data JPA don't seem to use database position field

I search to get

Order by
            samples0_.sampling_id ,
            samples0_.sample_letter asc

I tried to do: `id.samplingId`, `id.sampleLetter` I get this error:

> Sort expression ' id.sampleLetter: ASC' must only contain property
>     references or aliases used in the select clause

Comment: I have never had any issue sorting by embeddable ids, this is a bit odd. Do you mind adding your code where you are fetching your data?

Comment: does it work when you sort by `id.samplingId` and `id.sampleLetter`?

Comment: "In database sample, samplingId is position 0 and sampleLetter is position 1;" What does this mean??

Comment: it's the column order

Comment: The whole `String` and `Integer` and having only one `MapsId` concerns me.